# Do web browsers cache pages and only request if updated? Can they? Why/why not?

Tags: browser, cache

I'm just wondering if my web browser ever downloads the same page twice.

I speculate that in the future, web pages will merge with applications to the point were downloading a webpage is akin to updating an application.  There will be some way to tell if a site has been updated, and go from cache otherwise (some times offline). For instance, you go to a word editor site once, and as long as it's standalone (as in the site can be saved to desktop and work from there), you now have a word editor cached/~installed.  You can use the webapp without a connection, ect.

Anyways, do web browsers cache pages like that yet?  Or can they be made to easily?  And is there some reason they do, don't, can, or can't?

Thanks.

EDIT:  It ends up pages are cached.  Now all I think I need is an add-on that checks if a page has been updated, notifies me, and then only requests the page if I want to "update."  Assuming the page has somehow been labeled as a standalone web app.

Comment: Yes most browsers do cache. If you open your Dev Tools (F12), let's say in Chrome, then go to the Network tab, click Record, then refresh. You'll see a list of files that were pulled to the browser for the request, and other information about each file. One column, the status column, indicates the HTTP status code of the document. A 304 status code (NOT MODIFIED) means the document was unchanged on the server from that in cache, so the browser uses that in cache instead of retrieving a new file. Edit: BUT your browser will not use the cache if it can't communicate with the site.

Comment: Cool.  Good to know.  I'd never noticed the "work offline" mode in firefox.  I'm kind of surprised that some pages take so long to load now though.